# Taking into account weekends/holidays when using timedeltas in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, timedelta, shift

So heres a problem it took me a while to figure why its happening...

I have a dataframe of values with a datetime index of workdays.

Im adding a new column, 'ColB', which is always the same value as colA, EXCEPT where colA is 0. Then I want to use the *previous* days value of colA.

For example:

| Day | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-11-11 | 7 | 7 |
| 2019-11-12 | 3 | 3 |
| 2019-11-13 | 0 | 3 |
| 2019-11-14 | 5 | 5 |
| 2019-11-15 | 0 | 5 |

Note how colB on 2019-11-13 becomes the value of colA from 2019-11-12. Same on the 15th: colB takes colA from the 14th.

Ive used this list comprehension:

```
df.loc[:,'colB'] = [df.loc[d-pd.Timedelta(1,'d'),'ColA'] if df.loc[d,'ColA']==0 else df.loc[d,'ColA'] for d in df.index]
```

I thought it wasnt working (KeyError: Timestamp('2019-11-03 00:00:00')), but I discovered the problem occurs because I have a zero on a monday, and therefore no rows for `d-pd.Timedelta(1,'d')` which would be a sunday.

I suppose the same problem will happen when I have a zero the day after a holiday too.

To solve it, when col A is zero, I actually need to use the previous value in colA for colB, and NOT the previous DAYS value, as Ive done in the list comprehension.

Ive solved it by reindexing, using sequential numbers rather than dates, but I think its nicer to use the dates.

I tried shift:

```
df.loc[:,'colB'] = [df.loc[d,'ColA'].shift(-1) if df.loc[d,'ColA']==0 else df.loc[d,'ColA'] for d in df.index]
```

but get an error: `AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'shift'`

Can anyone see a simple way to do this without reindexing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.assign(B = df['A'].replace(0))
```

Output:

```
          Day  A  B
0  2019-11-11  7  7
1  2019-11-12  3  3
2  2019-11-13  0  3
3  2019-11-14  5  5
4  2019-11-15  0  5
```

Comment: Thats pretty cool, though way beyond my understanding. I dont understand why df['A'].replace(0) doesnt leave nans where there were zeros. Ive tested it in the program, and it uses the previous value in the A column, as it should,

Comment: Aha! "When value is not explicitly passed and to_replace is a scalar, list or tuple, replace uses the method parameter (default ‘pad’) to do the replacement." That was a tutorial and a half! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `shift()` method to shift the index by a given number of periods. `shift()` slides down values (not the index), which can be used to fill the missing values in a column based on the value of the previous row.

You can use it in combination with the `where()` function, which replaces values where the condition is False.

```
df['ColB'] = df['ColA'].where(df['ColA'] != 0, df['ColA'].shift(1))
```

This creates a new column 'ColB' and assigns it the value of 'ColA' if 'ColA' is not zero. If 'ColA' is zero, then it takes the value from the previous row of 'ColA'.

To also handle the first row, use the `fillna()` function. This function replaces NA/NaN values with a specified value.

In the example below, if the first row of 'ColA' is 0, it will be replaced with the second value from 'ColA'. If you want to replace it with another value, you can replace `df['ColA'][0]` below with the desired value.

```
df['ColB'] = df['ColA'].where(df['ColA'] != 0, df['ColA'].shift(1)).fillna(df['ColA'][0])
```

Comment: Wow,, that was fast! I was editing the question cos my way of using shift didnt work. Yours seems to work great! Thanks!